# using grep to parse non-reg directories

Tags: parsing, grep

I have a non-reg directory in which all performed test have a specific sub-directory named tc_TestName. In each of these subdirectories there is a log file call sim.log. I want to verify if the test is PASSED by searching for the string "TEST PASSED". So far I have performed the command
grep -rni --include "sim.log" "TEST PASSED" >& test_passed.txt
I am perfectly happy with the result, but since the sim.log files may be very big and I have more than 1000 tests, it takes quite a while to perform.
Is there any way to perform the search of the string "TEST PASSED" only on the last, let's say, 100 lines of my sim.log files ?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you need line numbers (based on your use of `-n` option), you cannot use `tail` to speed up because you'll lose line number information..

Comment: If you don't care about line numbers, you can use `find -name 'sim.log' -exec tail -q -n100 {} + | grep -i 'TEST PASSED'`

Comment: Another option is to use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) which by default will perform parallel search and has other speed optimizations..